# Генерация псевдослучайных чисел определенной длинны

Tags: c#, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Необходимо сгенерировать число состоящее из 16 цифр ,обязательно без знаковое.
просто int тут не влазит,а BigInteger великоват.
Числа должны быть уникальны,хотя бы в диапазоне 200 000 экземпляров.

```
long min = 1000000000000000;
long max = 9999999999999999;
Random rand = new Random();

long  id = rand.Next((Int32)(min >> 32), (Int32)(max >> 32));
id = (id << 32);
id = id | (long)rand.Next((Int32)min, (Int32)max);

return id;
```

в таком случае и не всегда на 16 символов, да и повторы бывают.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Мне что-то непонятно, что именно не получается.

Comment: `rand.Next(10000000, 100000000) * 100000000L + rand.Next(0, 100000000)`

Comment: Если уникальность обязательна - заведите `Hashset` и сохраняйте все сгенерированные числа туда, при генерации нового - проверяйте.

Comment: То, что зерно у Random — это Int32, — тонко намекает, что нормальных псевдослучайных 64 битов от него не добиться. Если не смущают дырки и неравномерность, можете формулой @Андрея воспользоваться. В вашей собственной формуле сдвиги границ лишние, посмотрите в отладчике, что вы в Next передаёте. Ну и при бинарной конкатенации чисел никто не обещает десятичной конкатенации, разумеется.

Comment: @Squidward  более уместно будет отказаться от Random?

Comment: @VladFinni Уместно определиться, какими свойствами должны обладать ваши 16 цифр. Вы как их использовать собираетесь?

Comment: @Squidward уникальный ключ, который в дальнейшем будет переобразован в QR-code.

Comment: @VladFinni GUID? В два раза больше бит, зато точно уникально.

Comment: @Squidward не до такой степени уникальной =)
Да и к тому же строго 16 цифр.

Comment: @Squidward, поясните про дырки и неравномерность в моем методе

Comment: @Squidward: велкам бэк

Comment: @Андрей Энтропия у псевдослучаного int и у псевдослучайного long, полученного конкатенацией двух последовательных псевдослучайных int, одинаковая — вторая половина long может быть вычислена по первой половине. Это к вопросу об осмыслленности подобной операции. Внутреннее состояние Random задаётся 32 битами, то есть чисто математически невозможно получить любое 64-битное число. Отрезок допустимых значений состоит из недостижимых дырок чуть менее, чем полностью. Random.Next даёт равномерное распределение, а вот какое распределение будет у объединённых значений — никто не гарантирует.

Comment: @Squidward, вашу мысль понял. Можно использовать 2 различных экземпляра `Random`, полученных, например, так: `Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`

Comment: @Андрей Уже лучше. Не решает всех проблем, но с практической точки зрения сойдёт, скорее всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант, рожденный в комментариях, вынесу в виде ответа:

```
class MyRandom
{
    Random rand1 = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    Random rand2 = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

    const int size = 200000;
    HashSet<long> values = new HashSet<long>();

    public long GetNext()
    {
        long next;
        do
            next = rand1.Next(10000000, 100000000) * 100000000L
                 + rand2.Next(100000000);
        while (values.Contains(next));
        values.Add(next);
        if (values.Count == size)
            values.Clear();
        return next;
    }
}
```