# Генерация случайного 128-битного числа

Tags: c#, криптография

Как лучше всего генерировать случайное 128-битное число в С#?
Я пока придумал такой способ: с помощью `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` сгенерировать массив байтов размером 16, потом склеить массив в одно число. Только вот вопрос: как клеить? Склеить в строку, а потом преобразовать ее в `BigInteger`, или сгенерировать `BigInteger` сразу из массива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам нужно именно *случайное число*, а не, допустим, *криптографически стойкое случайное число* или число с какими-то ещё дополнительными свойствами, вам вполне подойдёт очевидное:

```
// внимание! однопоточный код! <----------
static Random r = new Random();
static byte[] randomBytesBuf = new byte[16];
static BigInteger GenerateRandom128()
{
    r.NextBytes(randomBytesBuf);
    return new BigInteger(randomBytesBuf);
}
```

(Обратите внимание на обычную предосторожность при работе с классом `Random`: если ваш код многопоточный, вам следует заводить по экземпляру `Random` (а также для нашего случая `randomBytesBuf`) в *каждом* потоке.

Криптопровайдер по сравнению с простыми методами будет медленнее улитки, и без особой на то необходимости я бы не рекомендовал его использовать.

Comment: Недавно ещё пробегал вопрос, где обсуждалось, что криптографически стойкие случайные числа нельзя получить простой конкатенацией двух криптографически стойких чисел.

Comment: @AK: Правда? Интересно, не знал. Подéлитесь ссылкой, если вдруг вспомните?

Comment: Думаю, имеются ввиду комментарии к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677728/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b

Comment: @Андрей: Ах да, помню этот комментарий. Но я не уверен, так ли это для криптографического источника — он может вполне выдавать лишь часть битов текущего seed'а.